# How to print envelopes properly on LibreWriter

Tags: printing, libreoffice

I want to print a #10 envelope in LibreWriter on an HP M452dw printer.
No matter what settings I try it always shifts the print 4cm to the right.

Comment: Is this Ubuntu related?

Comment: Hmmmm. Unable to duplicate: I've used the LibreOffice #10 Template for years, and it's always printed perfectly.

Comment: Have you set up a CUPS ( http://localhost:631/admin ) queue with #10 Envelopes paper?

Comment: Solved in Ubuntu 20.04!